# PHP, Yii User Extension

Tags: php, yii, xampp

I try to install yii extension http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yii-user/ and try to insert command 'yiic migrate --migrationPath=user.migrations'. How to do it correctly that it works instead of:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\eshops\protected>..\framework\yiic migrate --migrationPath=modules.user.migrations
Error: The migration directory does not exist: modules.user.migrations
C:\xampp\htdocs\eshops\protected>cd ..
C:\xampp\htdocs\eshops>framework\yiic migrate --migrationPath=protected.modules.user.migrations
Error: The migration directory does not exist: protected.modules.user.migrations
C:\xampp\htdocs\eshops>cd protected
C:\xampp\htdocs\eshops\protected>..\framework\yiic migrate --migrationPath=user.migrations
Error: The migration directory does not exist: user.migrations
```

I have XAMPP and windows 7.

Thank you

Answer (score 5):

the answer is :

there is 2 files with the name `yiic.php`

1. ../yii/framwork/yiic.php
2. .../protected/yiic.php

you should use the second one

Answer (score 2):

Use `yiic migrate --migrationPath=application.modules.user.migrations`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the latest version of yii-user, it's more difficult than you think!
There's a couple of gotchas when installing yii-user and this article goes through them in order to get the migration to work.

http://www.bigsoft.co.uk/blog/index.php/2013/12/08/which-is-the-latest-version-of-yii-user